# fileignoreconfig in talisman are not considered in scan mode

Tags: git, pre-commit, talisman

I've added fileignoreconfig in .talismanrc. The observations are as follows

- when I ran `talisman --scan`, the fileignoreconfig are not considered and scans the whole commit history
- When I ran `talisman --ignoreHistory --scan`, the fileignoreconfig are included and scans the head

**Expectation**
fileignoreconfig should be included for all type of scans.

How to make talisman to include fileignoreconfig even for `talisman --scan`

**Code Reference**
https://github.com/thoughtworks/talisman/blob/f9b0c70b2b4da6f0144934ac3c186b9cc95ab83b/talismanrc/talismanrc.go#L104